# Login with twitter oAuth and Passport.js

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth, passport.js, passport-twitter

I'm building an application in node.js that allows to login with an twitter account.

The first time that I've run the code, wit worked, but some days later it simply returns some error.

I tried to change my twitter application configuration, but it doesn't works.

app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , io
  , _appS = require('./appServer')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy
  ;

var app = express()
  , PORT = 7777
  ;


passport.serializeUser(function ( user, done ) {
    done( null, user );
});

passport.deserializeUser(function ( obj, done ) {
    done( null, obj );
});

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy ({
        consumerKey : "consumer",
        consumerSecret : "secret",
        callbackURL : "http://127.0.0.1:7777/auth/twitter/callback"
    },
    function ( token, tokenSecret, profile, done ) {

        process.nextTick (function () {
            return done ( null, profile );
        });
    }
));

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({secret : 'argentina campeon'}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);

    app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
});

io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(PORT));

/**
 * ROUTES
 */

app.get(
    "/", 
    function ( req, res ) {
    if ( req.user ) {
        //hay usuario
        io.sockets.on('connection', function ( socket ) {
            _appS.init( req.user.id, socket );
        });

    }
        else
            res.redirect('/login');
    }
);

app.get(
    "/login", 
    function ( req, res ) {
        if ( ! req.user )
            res.render("login");
        else
            res.redirect('/');
    }
);

app.get(
    "/auth/twitter", 
    passport.authenticate('twitter'),
    function ( req, res ) { }
);

app.get(
    "/auth/twitter/callback", 
    passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect : '/login' }),
    function ( req, res ) {
        console.log( req.user );
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);

app.get(
    "/logout", 
    function ( req, res ) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

When I try to login, it redirects me to twitter to validate the app permissions, but it says:

> We are redirecting you to the application. This may take a few
>   minutes.

So, if I wait a few seconds, a new link appears:

> If your browser does not redirect you, please click here

So, when I click it, it now redirects me to my application, but now I'm getting an error:

```
Error: Failed to find request token in session at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\passport-twitter\node_modules\passport-oauth1\lib\strategy.js:142:54) at Strategy.authenticate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\passport-twitter\lib\strategy.js:85:40) at attempt (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:337:16) at authenticate (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:338:7) at callbacks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37) at param (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11) at pass (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5) at Router._dispatch (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5) at Object.router (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10) at next (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
```

The funny part is that in my console, I can see all the user data from Twitter after login, because in some part of my code I put `if ( req.user ) console.log( req.user );`

- I'm using the latest version of node.js and its packages (express, passport, twitter-passport, socket.io)
- I'm using windows 7

So, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

If this really is your code, and not something you substituted before posting here, then you're telling either Twitter or the client (I forget which) to call *itself* instead of your post-login GET call:

```
callbackURL : "http://127.0.0.1:7777/auth/twitter/callback"
```